# Cancel asynctask without instance (Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have multiple asynctask   in one activity in android and I usually call them like this:

```
new call_SOAPCheck().execute();
```

or like this

```
new MainActivity.DownloadTask(getApplicationContext()).execute("http://.....");
```

I want to cancel any asynctask running when pressing the back button, but since I don't create an instance I cant call  .cancell(true).

Is there a way to kill the asynctask running without the instance?

the reason I call them like that is that I need to execute them many times in the same activity, and if I declare them like "global" variables I get an error that I can only execute them once.

Also, there is no loop inside my asynctask so I can't check isCancelled() periodically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why not keep a reference, and recreate them:**

Instead of doing this:

```
new call_SOAPCheck().execute();
```

Do this:

```
//keep a global ref

call_SOAPCheck task;
```

Then whenever you want call task again and again, just recreate over and over. By doing this:

```
private void callTaskAgain(){

task = new call_SOAPCheck();
task.execute();

}
```